# Jquery mobile page flickers and blinks when dialog box is open and closed

Tags: javascript, android, cordova-2.0.0, jquery-mobile-dialog

I am creating an app in which i want to use a select option with long list for this i tried an example from [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/selects/custom-selects.php) but the problem is when tried the long list example in the emulator then the page starts flickering and blinking before opening the dialog and after closing the dialog can any one tell how to solve this issue is also google it and found many solution but none of them worked. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, comment the lines of code in jquery.mobile-1.x.x.js

```
 1. //meta.attr( "content", disabledZoom );

 2. //meta.attr( "content", enabledZoom );
```

Have a fun;